# Vector3.MoveTowards working fine but Vector2.MoveTowards not working in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm building an enemy pathing using waypoints in 2d Environment in UNITY

EnemyPathing.CS is attached to an Enemy Prefab Using Unity 2021.3

```
public class EnemyPathing : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
    [SerializeField] List<Transform> waypoints; 
    [SerializeField] float moveSpeed = 2f; int waypointIndex = 0;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        transform.position = waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position;
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Move();
    }
    
    private void Move()
    {
        if (waypointIndex <= waypoints.Count - 1)
        {
            var targetPosition = waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position;
            var movementThisFrame = moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

            // Issue here
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, movementThisFrame);

            if (transform.position == targetPosition)
            {
                waypointIndex++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Enemy stuck a `waypointIndex[0]` does not move next waypoint when I use Vector2MoveTowards

```
transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, movementThisFrame);
```

`Vector3.MoveTowards` works fine as it supposed to be
My question is Why `Vector2.MoveTowards` not working

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, movementThisFrame);
```

Comment: What happens when you debug

Answer (score 1):

According to description - and knowing that `Vector2.MoveTowards` itself works just fine - it sounds more like your object actually moves correctly. What is rather failing is your check for

```
if(transform.position == targetPosition)
```

is still comparing in 3D space so also taking the Z axis into account which is ignored/erased in `Vector2.MoveTowards`

=> In the case your `targetPosition` has any `z != 0` your check will forever fail.

I suppose it would work correctly if you also stop comparing the 3D vectors and rather do

```
if((Vector2)transform.position == (Vector2)targetPosition)
```